# create flag based on row values in grep()

Tags: r, if-statement, data-manipulation

I have a 10-row data frame of tweets about `potatoes` and need to flag them based on the punctuation each `tweet` contains (questions marks or exclamation points). The `grep` function will return row numbers where these characters appear:

```
grep("\\?", potatoes$tweet)
grep("!", potatoes$tweet)
```

I've tried to create the flag variable `question` with `mutate` in dplyr as shown...

```
potatoes$question <- NA
potatoes <- mutate(potatoes, question = +row_number(grep("\\?", potatoes$tweet)))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Column `question` must be length 10 (the number of rows) or one, not 3
```

I'm also happy to consider more elegant solutions than conditioning on the output of `grep`. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grepl` instead of `grep` as `grep` returns the index/position where the matches occurs, whereas `grepl` returns a logical `vector` where TRUE denotes the matching element and FALSE non-matching.  It can be used as a flag

```
i1 <- grepl("!", potatoes$tweet)
```

and if we need to change to row numbers,

```
potatoes$question <- i1 * seq_len(nrow(potatoes$sweet))
```

---

Similarly, `grep` with row index can be used for assignment

```
i2 <- grep("!", potatoes$tweet)
potatoes$question[i2] <- seq_len(nrow(potatoes))[i2]
```

Comment: beautiful - thank you! The edits make the answer even more helpful/intuitive

Comment: if you already use tidyverse functions then also consider `stringr::str_detect` as a replacement